# Replacing Characters Repeated 3+ times

Tags: regex, r

In R, how do i replace characters repeating 3 or more times with 1 or 2 repetitions of that character only?

For example `cakkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeee` becomes `cake` or `cakkee`. Another example would be zzzzzzzzz, becomes z or zz.

Comment: So when is it cake and when cakkee? Is it decided randomly with probability 1/2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try

```
gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "cake"  "z"     "zzaab"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("cakkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeee", "zzzzzzzzz", "zzaab")
```